# What unit of measurement is the duplicate complexity setting in for TeamCity's duplicates finder?

Tags: .net, teamcity

My team and I are setting up TeamCity's duplicate finder currently. We are looking at the option marked "Ignore duplicates with complexity simpler than" and cannot find any reference as to what unit of measurement it is using. The TeamCity documentation only mentions that it is used to set the complexity and my GoogleFu is failing to help me. Does anyone have any idea what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been years since I asked this, but I have discovered that this feature meant "cyclomatic complexity" when it mentioned complexity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Answer (score -1):

It is internal unit of measurement used by Resharper commandline tool (which does the actual job). As this blog post says:

> Allows setting a threshold for code complexity of duplicated
>   fragments. The fragments with lower complexity are discarded as
>   non-duplicates. The value for this option is provided in relative
>   units. Using this option, you can filter out equal code fragments that
>   present no semantic duplication.

I am not sure about the underlying implementation, though. Most likely, it is a size of an AST  fragments that are used for search.